# internet explorer batch or vbs file

Tags: security, internet-explorer, vbscript, batch-file

Is it possible to write a .bat/vbs file to change IE7/8 security settings?

I need to change a couple of internet explorer security settings on about 100 computers, and it would be good if I could do this via a .bat/vbs file as I don't know how to use group policies.

Comment: May be of interest: http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=692419

Comment: Security zones registry entries, flags etc listed: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/182569

Answer (score 1):

Follow the link @Kul-Tigin comment. If you have remote command line access to all machines, what you can do is setup the settings on one machine (or a test machine), then export the registry tree/entries of the IE security settings. Once that is done, you can run the `REG IMPORT` command on your exported `.reg` file remotely to all workstations.

We use `PSEXEC` for remote command line usage.